# CUDA out of memory with all large language models

Tags: memory, pytorch, google-colaboratory

Everytime I try to fine-tune a model and import it into my google colab i get the following error:
CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 4.29 GiB. GPU 0 has a total capacty of 14.75 GiB of which 2.05 GiB is free. Process 40571 has 12.70 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 11.66 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 28.90 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF

I tried a batch size of 4 but still gives me the same error. Currently with the free GPU i have 15 GB RAM available but literally have not been able to train anything with it

Would appreciate any advice

I tried smaller batch sizes, but to no avail